# Click event is never fired on L.vectorGrid layer

Tags: leaflet, label, vector-tiles

I have a simple leaflet webpage using a vectorGrid to fetch mvt tiles. The fetching and visualising works fine. But I'm trying to show info with the click() event. Seems like it never gets fired though. Not even the console logs show up.

Here's the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-sA+zWATbFveLLNqWO2gtiw3HL/lh1giY/Inf1BJ0z14="
     crossorigin=""/>
<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-o9N1jGDZrf5tS+Ft4gbIK7mYMipq9lqpVJ91xHSyKhg="
     crossorigin=""></script>
     
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.vectorgrid@latest/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js"></script>
     
</head>

<style>
#map { height: 512px; }
</style>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>

var map = L.map('map').setView([51.054880442055975, 3.7235876996338439], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var tiles = L.vectorGrid
  .protobuf('http://185.187.169.142:3000/rpc/shalocmo.fn_responses_zones_penetration/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?request_id=40368320-5092-11ed-b062-7d13ebe9390b', {
    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
      'penetration': {
        fill: true,
        weight: 1,
        fillColor: '#e5b404',
        color: 'black',
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        opacity: 0.4
      }
    }
  })
  .on('click', function (e) { 
    console.log("clicked");
    L.popup()
    .setContent(e.layer.properties.home_zone_code)
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .openOn(map)
    })
  .addTo(map);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add this function to your code because it seems to be missing

```
                        L.DomEvent._fakeStop = function () {
                            return true;
                            }
```